# display problems of zsh in archlinux

Tags: zsh, archlinux

Currently I have installed zsh in archlinux (in gnome 3), and every time when I open the terminal, there are 3 "???" before, then I have to change it manually on the options

Actually I have already set the default locale to UTF-8, and it works in the console before I enter the gnome.But after I enter the gnome interface, it did not work.

After I have changed that, it works, but there is another problem, everytime I type a command and press tab, all the command will be shifted right by 2 words, for example if I type ls, it will display like this:

ls becomes lsls
vim becomes vivim

The first 2 letters cannot be cleared, which is very annoying, can anyone help me about this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got how to solve this question
After we enabled the locale in the /etc/locale.gen and use locale-gen to generate it. I have to also set the locale system-wide, 
create the /etc/locale.conf file
and set the default locale

## localectl set-locale LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"

Then if I exit and log again, the oh-my-zsh will work fine.